# Laravel variable value being lost when passing to a function

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

```
$country = DB::table('location_countries')->where('name','India')->first();
$country_id = $country['_id'];
echo $country_id;
$states = DB::table('location_states')->where('country_id',$country_id)->first();
echo $states['name'];
```

above is the code i am running in the controller i have used jenseggers/mongodb for the mongodb connection.

till this part of code i can see the response when i do the echo

```
$country = DB::table('location_countries')->where('name','India')->first();
$country_id = $country['_id'];
echo $country_id;
```

after i pass the `$country_id` to the function as below it shows no response

```
$states = DB::table('location_states')->where('country_id',$country_id)->first();
echo $states['name'];
```

if i directly pass the string like the below code instead of passing the `$country_id` variable then i get a response but if i pass a variable there is no response.

```
$states = DB::table('location_states')->where('country_id','value-here')->first();
```

Why is this happening and how to bypass this.

Comment: Try $states = DB::table('location_states')->where('country_id', '=' ,$country_id)->first();

Comment: Tried this before but it didn't work.

Comment: Try dd($states); just below that line and see o/p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query returns an object not an array so use it like this:

If you want to retrieve the **id** column: `$country->id;`

The same is true for **states**, e.g., the **name** column: `$states->name;`

Also try with `trim` maybe there is any **blank** space:

```
where('country_id', trim($country_id))
```

Comment: This is also not working as i have tried this before.

Comment: What  is your , `echo $country_id;` ?

Comment: it is echoing a value for country  id

Comment: Also try with trim : `where('country_id',trim($country_id))`

Comment: worked perfectly with trim. Whats the logic behind it

Comment: Sometime it looks same but it actually have some Blank spaces.

Comment: You can mark this answer as solved answer to know another as this question is solved.